# Determining method dependency in an Object Oriented class

Tags: java, oop, code-analysis, static-analysis

Is anyone aware of any methodology to try and determine the method and instance variable dependencies that exact for a single method in an object oriented class? For example, if I have the following code:

```
public class Foo {
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Foo() {
      x = 1;
      y = 2;
   }

   public void doFoo() {
      doJaa(x);
      x++;      
   }

   private void doJaa(int xVar) {
      System.out.println("x is: " + xVar);
   }

   private void nop() {
      System.out.println("Nada!");
   }
}
```

What I was looking to do was to take a method, say method 'doFoo' and determine all of its instance variable and method dependencies (I would like to determine these dependencies at ***build-time***). In this case, those dependencies would be 'int x', 'Foo()' and 'doJaa(int x)'. There are no dependencies between method 'nop' and 'doJaa' however. Is there a name for this type of analysis, just so I can search for more information around it? I am aware of the following analysis techniques

1. Control flow graph (No use to me)
2. Program Dependence graph
3. System Dependence graph

1 isn't much use to me as it's concerned with control flow. 2 is concerned with control and data dependencies either within a single method or across method boundaries. I have researched this and it isn't really what I want as it's too granular. 3 is a follow on from 2 and again is way too granular for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only one tool JDepend: http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html

But I doubt it works on one method basics. if it does not help you you need to implement your own logic probably using byte-code manipulation (engineering) library.

Comment: Thanks lads. I think I'll do it myself. Soot API will give me the analysis I need. I was just hoping that there were some papers out there on this topic, but I can't seem to find any. I can only find info on Program Dependence graphs, System dependence graphs and Control Flow graphs.

Comment: Excuse me for a question, but why do you need this?

Comment: Because I want to extract code from the class that is only relevant to a particular method. In other words, given a method, I want to extract all code from the class that it is dependent upon so that I can get an executable program slice.

Answer (score 1):

for such special purpose, it is hard to find any off shelf software for you to use.

it can be done by static analyzing of  java byte code, i don't know why you need such function, what the real benefit to analyze it. if it is just a special purpose for you, i think you need to write such tool by your self.